# libpng error: Read Error while building ionic for android

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am getting this error when i build for android -

`ionic build android`

error -

`AAPT err(Facade for 259068547): libpng error: Read Error

AAPT err(Facade for 1123857185): libpng error: Read Error

AAPT err(Facade for 594029608): libpng error: Read Error

FAILED

FAILURE:
Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':mergeArmv7DebugResources'.

>
Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

- Try:

Run with
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
 or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.193 secs

Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"f:\D\srcc\proj\platforms\
android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b f:\D\srcc\proj\platforms\android\build.gradle -
Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"`

How can i find the exact error or solve this issue? Anyone please?

Answer (score 1):

I also meet this [build fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHdV3.png) problem due to I run `ionic resources`, at this time my ionic version is 2.1.1, I find there is something wrong with one image in the path `resources\android\splash` [incomplete image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8acdf.png)

after I run `npm uninstall ionic -g` and reinstall it, now version is 2.1.14, then delete the folder `resources\android` run `ionic resources android --force` and `ionic build android` , the problem is solved.